# JQuery Corners - Visual Studio 2010 Error

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, jquery-plugins

I am trying to work out why I can't get JQuery Rounded Corners working when attempting to implement within Visual Studio 2010.

I have the following defined in the Site.Master:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js" language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.js" language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.corners.min.js" language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm then trying to implement JQuery Rounded Corners within Default.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// add code here
$('.box').corners('20px');
});
</script>
```

However, when I run the site, the debugger appears with an error message:

*microsoft jscript runtime error: object doesn't support this property or method*

The script is invoking the error on: $('.box').corners('20px');

Has anyone managed to get JQuery Rounded Corners working in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: can you do a `alert(typeof $("foo").corners)` and tell us what happens?

Comment: Hey, when I insert that line of code, I get 'undefined'. I tried with a number of different class names and div ID's. e.g. alert(typeof $('.box').corners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because your included src= for the files is not correct.

you can use ResolveUrl in your script block, take a look:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>"/>
```

IMHO, The better solution is to include this file from any free CDN provider out there, here is an example:

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js
```

so your line should be like this:

`<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" />`

if you are using asp.net, and using ScriptReference and all the Microsoft Ajax stuff, you can simply use this one:

**Update:**  Ben, Kindly replace the Script blocks in your `head` section with these ones:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.corners.min.js")%>"></script>
```

The problem is fixed by just closing the Script blocks by `</script>`  instead of ending them with `/>`

very funny, right? ;)

let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thanks for your time, however I still get the same error.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip regarding including the file from CDN, but this application will not be connected to the Internet when it's deployed. All resources need to be included within the release.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the main cause for your problem, can you give us a published page , so we may investigate more?

Comment: did you use the "ResolveUrl" solution, and still not working?

can you use Firebug and check if the jQuery file is loaded or not?

Comment: yeah, I tried to implement ResolveURL. My project is only in the very early stages, download a copy of it from here: http://www.2way.net.au/downloads/ContentManager_v1.zip

Comment: I've fixed your solution, I will edit my answer, so wait a minute and let me know if it worked.

Comment: +1 the `</script>` is very likely the trick; I've seen that before